# When launching java app as Mac app there default java process name and About description instead of mine

Tags: java, macos, shell, installation, applescript

I have a number of jar-files, some resources, h2 database, etc. in my project. To create **Mac application** I used Platypus. To run my application **shell script** was used.

However at this case when application starts then **separate java process** starts and there **neither proper name of the app nor proper Abou**t description in Mac menu. Also Terminal starts that is not wanted.

How I should launch the app to avoid this drawbacks so that the name of the app and About description were the right ones?

What I see now (name and About):

[image]

[image]

My launching **shell script** is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

export IRULE_HOME="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd -P)"

export IRULE_LANG=en
export IRULE_REGION=EN
export IRULE_XMS=-Xms256m
export IRULE_XMX=-Xmx1024m
export LOG4J_CONFIGURATION=${IRULE_HOME}/conf/log4j2.xml
export JAVA_HOME="${IRULE_HOME}/jre/Contents/Home"

export DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="$IRULE_XMS \
              $IRULE_XMX \
              -Dlog4j.configuration=file:"${LOG4J_CONFIGURATION}" \
              -Dirule.home=${IRULE_HOME} \
              -Dirule.client.logs.path=${IRULE_HOME}/logs \
              -Duser.language="${IRULE_LANG}" \
              -Duser.region="${IRULE_REGION}" \
              $JAVA_OPTS"


export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${JAVA_HOME}:${PATH}
export CLASSPATH=${IRULE_HOME}/lib/*:${IRULE_HOME}/conf:${JAVA_HOME}/lib/jfxrt.jar;

exec ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -Xdock:name="iRule Reader" -Xdock:icon=${IRULE_HOME}/image/irule.png ${DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS} -classpath "${CLASSPATH}" com.spi2.Main $*
```

How I created the app by Platypus. The process is simple: I set my shell-script and add all my resources. Also I can set up the icon. And I add Credits.html to allow About description as said in documentation:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try running the Java apps/processes in [headless mode](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html).
Try adding this option to your `DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS`:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

But since your Java app has a GUI, that may not be a viable option.

You could also try implementing your own handlers for the system menu using the `com.apple.eawt` Apple Extensions classes (ex. AboutHandler, QuitHandler, etc.), as stated in their [Java Development Guide for Mac docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/07-NativePlatformIntegration/NativePlatformIntegration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001909-211884-TPXREF130):

> The next step to customizing your application menu is to have your own
>   handling code called when certain items in the application menu are
>   chosen. Apple provides functionality for this in the `com.apple.eawt.*`
>   Java classes. The Application and ApplicationAdaptor classes provide a
>   way to handle the Preferences, About, and Quit items.

I could not find the actual API docs though.
Here are some other SO links which may help:

- [What's the alternative to using the now deprecated com.apple.eawt.ApplicationAdapter in Java Swing apps on the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5130074/2745495)
- [Can Java 7 use Apple Java Extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15048220/2745495)
- [How to get Apple Java Extensions (com.apple.eawt) work on JDK 7 and higher?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24479016/2745495)

Comment: Yes. With this option there is an exception: Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException ... However thanks for the information, I'll see these approaches.